# Cancel button disappears after dismissing UISearchBar keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, cancel-button

I have the following lines in my code:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

When I tap the searchButton, the keyboard is dismissed and the cancel button disappears.

What is the solution ?

Comment: what your purpose ?

Comment: I think that your constraints are messed up. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @childrenOurFuture When the user starts searching, the navigation bar will be hidden and the cancel button will show. The navigation bar will always be hidden until the user taps the cancel button

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp the cancel button is built-in the UISearchBar and constraints cannot be added to it

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED !**

I have solved the problem by adding UIButton [cancelButton] beside the UISearchBar, and adds the width constraint as @IBOutlet. Now, instead of showing the cancelButton of the searchBar, I'm changing the width of the cancelButton to show or hide as follow:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
        self.widthConstraint.constant = 44.0
        self.cancelButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
        self.widthConstraint.constant = 0.0
        self.cancelButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```